# Tooltip com mouseover dentro de uma coluna de um grid js

Tags: javascript, css

Tenho esse grid:

```
function CarregarGrid() {
            $('#gridConteudo').jqGrid({
                colModel: [{ width: 80, name: 'COD_OPERADORA', index: 'COD_OPERADORA', label: 'Operadora', formatter: GridOperadoraFormatter },
                           { name: 'NOM_OPERADORA', index: 'NOM_OPERADORA', hidden: true },
                           { width: 80, name: 'SITUACAO', index: 'SITUACAO', label: 'Situação' },
                           { width: 90, name: 'DT_EXCLUSAO_OPERADORA', index: 'DT_EXCLUSAO_OPERADORA', label: 'Dt. Exclusão Operadora', sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: "d/m/Y", newformat: 'd/m/Y' } },
                           { width: 130, name: 'COD_REDE', index: 'COD_REDE', label: 'Rede', formatter: GridRedeFormatter },
                           { name: 'NOM_REDE', index: 'NOM_REDE', hidden: true },
                           { width: 90, name: 'DT_EXCLUSAO_REDE', index: 'DT_EXCLUSAO_REDE', label: 'Dt. Exclusão Rede' },
                           { width: 120, name: 'COD_PRESTADOR_SUBSTITUTO', index: 'COD_PRESTADOR_SUBSTITUTO', label: 'Prestador Substituto', formatter: GridPrestadorSubstitutoFormatter },
                           { name: 'NOME_PRESTADOR_SUBSTITUTO', index: 'NOME_PRESTADOR_SUBSTITUTO', hidden: true },
                           { width: 115, name: 'DESC_MOTIVO_EXCLUSAO', index: 'DESC_MOTIVO_EXCLUSAO', label: 'Motivo Exclusão' },
                           { width: 95, name: 'DT_NOTIF_VOLUNTARIA', index: 'DT_NOTIF_VOLUNTARIA', label: 'Dt. Notificação Excl. Voluntária', sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: "d/m/Y", newformat: 'd/m/Y' } },
                           { width: 90, name: 'DT_LIMITE_ATD', index: 'DT_LIMITE_ATD', label: 'Dt. Limite Realização', sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: "d/m/Y", newformat: 'd/m/Y' } },
                           { width: 90, name: 'DT_LIMITE_REMESSA', index: 'DT_LIMITE_REMESSA', label: 'Dt. Limite Apresentação', sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: "d/m/Y", newformat: 'd/m/Y' } },
                           { width: 90, name: 'DT_LIMITE_RECURSO', index: 'DT_LIMITE_RECURSO', label: 'Dt. Limite Reapresentação', sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: "d/m/Y", newformat: 'd/m/Y' } },
                           { width: 90, name: 'DT_FIM_EXIBE_DIRECIONAMENTO', index: 'DT_FIM_EXIBE_DIRECIONAMENTO', label: 'Dt. Fim Exibe Site', sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: "d/m/Y", newformat: 'd/m/Y' } },
                           { width: 100, name: 'OBSERVACAO', index: 'OBSERVACAO', label: 'Observação' }],
                url: urlControle + '/GetPrestadorOperadora',
                mtype: 'POST',
                postData: { "pEXEC": function () { return $("#pEXEC").val(); }, "pCodPrestadorTS": function () { return $("#hidCodPrestadorTS").val(); } },
                jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, root: function (obj) { return obj.Items; } },
                datatype: "json",
                autowidth: true,
                shrinkToFit: false,
                forceFit: true,
                loadonce: true,
                loadError: function (xhr, st, err) { $.notificacoes.erro("@TopSaudeResource.notificacao_erro_transacao"); },
                loadComplete: function () {

                    if ($('#hidCodPrestadorTS').val() != '') {

                        var linhas = $("#gridConteudo").getDataIDs();

                        if (linhas.length <= 0) {
                            $('#divConteudo').hide();
                            $.notificacoes.erro("Prestador não está excluído em nenhuma Operadora e/ou Rede");
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#divConteudo').removeAttr('style');
                            $('#divConteudo').show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            $('#gridConteudo').jqGrid('setLabel', 'COD_OPERADORA', '', { 'text-align': 'left' });
            $('#gridConteudo').jqGrid('setLabel', 'SITUACAO', '', { 'text-align': 'left' });
            $('#gridConteudo').jqGrid('setLabel', 'DT_EXCLUSAO_OPERADORA', '', { 'text-align': 'left' });
            $('#gridConteudo').jqGrid('setLabel', 'COD_REDE', '', { 'text-align': 'left' });
            $('#gridConteudo').jqGrid('setLabel', 'DT_EXCLUSAO_REDE', '', { 'text-align': 'left' });
            $('#gridConteudo').jqGrid('setLabel', 'COD_PRESTADOR_SUBSTITUTO', '', { 'text-align': 'left' });
            $('#gridConteudo').jqGrid('setLabel', 'DESC_MOTIVO_EXCLUSAO', '', { 'text-align': 'left' });
            $('#gridConteudo').jqGrid('setLabel', 'DT_NOTIF_VOLUNTARIA', '', { 'text-align': 'left' });
            $('#gridConteudo').jqGrid('setLabel', 'DT_LIMITE_ATD', '', { 'text-align': 'left' });
            $('#gridConteudo').jqGrid('setLabel', 'DT_LIMITE_REMESSA', '', { 'text-align': 'left' });
            $('#gridConteudo').jqGrid('setLabel', 'DT_LIMITE_RECURSO', '', { 'text-align': 'left' });
            $('#gridConteudo').jqGrid('setLabel', 'DT_FIM_EXIBE_DIRECIONAMENTO', '', { 'text-align': 'left' });
            $('#gridConteudo').jqGrid('setLabel', 'OBSERVACAO', '', { 'text-align': 'left' });
        }
```

Preciso colocar um tooltip dentro da coluna `OBSERVACAO`. Esse é o meu tooltip que eu fiz(exemplo que peguei na net) e funciona, pois já testei em uma página html simples. O problema é chamar dentro desse grid. Veja o css que monta o tooltip:

```
.tooltip {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #039;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: help;
        }

        .tooltip:hover {
            background: transparent;
            color: #f00;
            z-index: 25;
        }

        .tooltip span {
            display: none;
        }

        .tooltip:hover span {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            width: 210px;
            top: 20px;
            left: 0;
            font-size: 12px;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #999;
            background: #e0ffff;
            color: #000;
        }
```

Como chamo isso de dentro da coluna supra citada?

Comment: No seu exemplo o que irá ficar no tooltip é o que estiver dentro do `span`, e dentro do `a` ficaria o texto para "passar o mouse", como [pode ser visto aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/3hg5v0t0/). Minha dúvida é: O campo Observacao se encaixa em qual dos dois textos? O dentro do `span` ou dentro do `a`?

Comment: É uma coluna do grid. Terei que mudar e é essa a minha dúvida. Como passar para uma coluna criada dentro de javascript.

Comment: Sim, mas minha dúvida (sobre sua dúvida) é: O que ficará dentro do tooltip? A descrição ficaria na tabela e no tooltip?

Comment: @Randrade, desculpe-me. O que vai dentro do tooltip é o que estiver no campo `Observacao`. Bem lembrado e havia me esquecido disso.

Answer (score 0):

Nessa linha:

`{ width: 100, name: 'OBSERVACAO', index: 'OBSERVACAO', label: 'Observação' }],`

Coloque no final:

`class: 'alwaysShow'`

Resultado:

`{ width: 100, name: 'OBSERVACAO', index: 'OBSERVACAO', label: 'Observação', class: 'tooltip' }],`

Mas isso é na coluna. Seu **tooltip** está aplicando em um elemento `a`.

Comment: Então, eu me perco um pouco quanto a isso. Como eu atribua a coluna do grid passado.

Comment: Foi isso que eu postei aí. Você vai aplicar a coluna *observação* o **tooltip**. Você testou o código ?

Comment: Tao, fiz isso e não funcionou. `{ width: 100, name: 'OBSERVACAO', index: 'OBSERVACAO', label: 'Observação', class:'tooltip' }`

Comment: Mas você alterou seu `css` tirando o `a.` da frente ?

Comment: Sim, inclusive fiz uma edição já sem o `a`